Metro routes have disappeared from Google Maps
From today (August 1st) Metro routes have disappeared from my Google Maps. I see only bus routes.
I didn't change anything in the settings. Help me solve this problem!
From today (August 1st) Metro routes have disappeared from my Google Maps. I see only bus routes.
I didn't change anything in the settings. Help me solve this problem!
